# How to disable log4j in web environment?

Tags: java, log4j

Can any one please tell me how to disable log4j in web environment? In production environment without affecting the code, how to disable logging mechanism from our code?

Answer (score 0):

You probebly have log4j.properties file, you also have report levels , if you current level is `ERROR` or something that is not `OFF` , you should change it to `OFF` : than no reports will be written.

here is a [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm) to the different reporting levels allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your log4j.properties file.  If you cannot do that, you can use the slf4j project to make your log4j calls go into slf4j which you in turn can tell to use any logging backend you want.  Either the slf4j-jdk14 which make it go into standard logging which most container handle, or slf4j-nop which make slf4j silent.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an XML configuration for log4j, you could enable support for 'hot' configuration changes. For example, to poll the configuration for changes every 10 seconds, load your config like this:

```
DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch("log4j.xml", 10000);
```

This way, you could change log levels without changing code and even without restarting your application.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling logging completely should be considered carefully. An better option would be do deactivate/change the log level on the package level in log4j.properties:

```
# Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package com.foo.
log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN
```